# Storing hierarchical data as a list of matrices in R

Tags: r, dataset, matrix, hierarchical

Noob R question here from a Matlab/Python user.  I have a dataset with hundreds of different users, each of whom has a unique number of rows of data, and would like to store the data as a list of matrices.  So user 1 may have a matrix of 500 rows, user 2 may have a matrix of 250, and so on.  This will be used as the inputs for a hierarchical logit with a mixture of normals to explain each user's betas. Column 1 of my dataset is a user id, and the rest of the cols are numerical values.

```
data <- read.csv("hierarchical_dataset.csv", header=FALSE)
nlgtt = length(table(data[[1]]))                          # number of users
users = names(table(data[[1]]))                           # user ids
```

All good so far, but here is where I'm getting my error:

```
TV = matrix()
testdata = list()

for (i in 1:nlgtt)
{   TV[i] = matrix(table(data[[1]])[[i]])                 # number of rows per user
    print(TV[i])                                          # should equal the below line
    print(dim(data[data[[1]] == users[i], ]))             # should equal the above line
    testdata[i] = data[data[[1]] == users[i], ]           # store hierarchically by user
}
```

When I run the above, the printed values match, so the correct data are being retrieved, but then I get simple repetitions of the `users[i]` value (the user id) for each `testdata[i]`, and also a `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` error. I'm sure this is just a simple formatting issue, but have looked around and failed to turn up anything that resolves my problem. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `base::lapply` from the `apply` family functions. Please see the example below.

```
dataset <- data.frame(user_id = c(1,1,2), variable_a = c(1,2,3))
lapply(unique(dataset$user_id), function(id) dataset[dataset$user_id == id,])
```

The output gives a 2 element list with matrices of user_id and variable_a, where each element is unique by user.